# How to do cumulative sum on RMySQL? Works in phpMyAdmin but gives error in R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I need to find the cumulative frequency by adding values from 2 columns and this is how i tried on phpMyAdmin. But when I tried in R language it gives me an error.

```sql
SELECT time.month, 
       hotel.state, 
       hotel.name, 
       income                                        AS 'Checkout Income', 
       booking.expected_income                       AS 'Future Income', 
       ( @sumvariable := @sumvariable + income 
                         + booking.expected_income ) AS 'Cumulative Income' 
FROM   checkout 
       INNER JOIN booking 
               ON checkout.checkout_id = booking.bookings_id 
       INNER JOIN time 
               ON checkout.timeid = time.timeid 
       INNER JOIN hotel 
               ON checkout.hotelid = hotel.hotelid 
WHERE  hotel.category = '4-star'
```

This is the error I'm getting from R using RMySQL:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT time.month, hotel.state,income, 
>                        booking.expected_In' at line 2

[image: This is what I got as result in phpMyAdmin]

Please help me out.

Comment: Means your this query is working fine in phpMyAdmin???

Comment: provide us your table structure.

Comment: Or u can create SQL fiddle demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: yes. and its working on R when i remove the line "SET @SumVariable := 0;". But then the cumulative frequency gives null null null null

Comment: You say, yo are getting this error `Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT time.month, hotel.state,income, booking.expected_In' at line 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RMySQL, like most APIs in the R DBI family (ROracle, RPostgreSQL, RSQLite, odbc, etc.), multiple DDL/DML statements such as `SET ...; SELECT ...;` in same call are not supported where only the first statement is executed. You can have multiple `SELECT` and then use [`dbNextResult`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf). In PHPMyAdmin (an IDE), multiple lines to even full length SQL scripts can be run in query window.

Hence, you will need to make multiple query calls, one to initialize the parameter and then one to run the query:

```
dbSendQuery(con, 'SET @SumVariable := 0;')             # PARAM SAVED IN SESSION
df <- dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT ...original query...')
```

---

**Correlated Subquery**

With that said, consider one statement using a correlated aggregate subquery which adds a lengthy nested query due to the multiple `JOIN`. This can be reduced significantly once MySQL in a future version supports CTEs. Below correlates using the `timeid` field assumed to be unique and ascending order (adjust in `WHERE` clause as needed).

```sql
SELECT time.month, 
       hotel.state, 
       hotel.name, 
       income                                        AS 'Checkout Income', 
       booking.expected_income                       AS 'Future Income', 

       (SELECT SUM(income + sub_b.expected_income)            
        FROM   checkout sub_c
               INNER JOIN booking sub_b
                       ON sub_c.checkout_id = sub_b.bookings_id 
               INNER JOIN time sub_t
                       ON sub_c.timeid = sub_t.timeid 
               INNER JOIN hotel sub_h
                       ON sub_c.hotelid = sub_h.hotelid 
        WHERE  sub_h.category = '4-star' 
          AND  sub_t.time_id <= time.time_id)        AS 'Cumulative Income' 

FROM   checkout 
       INNER JOIN booking 
               ON checkout.checkout_id = booking.bookings_id 
       INNER JOIN time 
               ON checkout.timeid = time.timeid 
       INNER JOIN hotel 
               ON checkout.hotelid = hotel.hotelid 
WHERE  hotel.category = '4-star' 
ORDER BY time.time_id;
```

**Stored Procedure**

Alternatively, save your multiple lines in a stored procedure and call it from R. In fact, there is an ongoing debate of pros and cons regarding efficiency, maintainability, and usability of saving SQL in application code (i.e., R) or as a stored procedure.

- MySQL *(run once)*

  ```sql
  DELIMITER //

  CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_proc
  BEGIN
     SET ...;
     SELECT ...;
  END //

  DELIMITER ;
  ```
- R

  ```r
  conn <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname="databasename", host="hostname",
                    username="username", password="password")
  df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "CALL my_stored_proc()")
  dbDisconnect(conn)
  ```